# Prevent right-click on HTML5 video tag

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, video-streaming, html5-video, mp4

In my website I am using html5 video tag. I have disabled the download button from the menu. But if I right click and click "Save video" I get the complete video in mp4 format.

However I've tried the same thing in Prime video and Netfix, and the option 'Save Video' when right clicking does not appear.

How they achieve that?

Comment: Friendly reminder: even if you _try_, and make it so you can't just right-click and download it, which is possible, if the client can see the video and display it, the client can save it. This is how youtube-dl works. They figured out how it sends the data to the browser, but these tools just save it instead. DRM helps, but DRM isn't perfect. So don't equate "You can't right click and save" with "the client can't download it if they really try". If end user is determined enough, they do it. Consider putting it in your terms of use instead.

Comment: @fgonzalez Asking how to disable right-click is not the same as asking how Netflix protects their videos... A "mouse-click" event cannot also be a "video bytes" protection.

Comment: PS: Try: `<video oncontextmenu="return false;" width="320" height="240" controls>`... The contextmenu is what you see whenever you right-click on some (video) Element.